# Ordering doesn't hold on SortedSet

Tags: scala

I have the following class with a defined ordering:

```
case class Offer(id: Int, amount: Int, interestRate: Double) extends Ordered[Offer] {

  def compare(that: Offer) = that.interestRate.compareTo(this.interestRate)

}
```

I declared a SortedSet of `Offer`, where I also defined the same ordering:

```
  val currentOffers: SortedSet[Offer] = SortedSet.empty[Offer](Ordering[Double].on[Offer](_.interestRate))
```

However, if I add:

```
Offer(1, 5, 4.0)
Offer(2, 5, 0.5)
Offer(3, 5, 1.5)
```

And then I extract the smallest element using `currentOffers.min`, I get:

```
Offer(1, 5, 4.0)
```

Instead of:

```
Offer(2, 5, 0.5)
```

Why is the ordering not respected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is respected.  `min` uses the default ordering for the object, which you have supplied, and it orders things backwards (`that compare this` not `this compare that`--did you intend that or is this a mistake?).  `min` is not specific to sorted collections--it will work on anything.

If you want to use the supplied ordering, use `head`: `SortedSet`'s entire point is that it sorts elements from least to greatest.  And unlike `min`, which will check everything just to be sure, `head` just gets what was already sorted to the front.

That `min` and `head` are not necessarily the same on `SortedSet` is a little nonintuitive, admittedly, but there is at least a bit of justification for why.